# How can I check it with regular Expression?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a long input string that contains certain field names in-bedded in it.  For instance:

```
SELECT some-name, some-name FROM [some-table] WHERE [some-column] = 'some-value'
```

The actual field name may change, but it is always in the form of `word-word`.  I need to perform a regex replace on the string so that the output will look like this:

```
SELECT some - name, some - name FROM [some-table] WHERE [some-column] = 'some - value'
```

In other words, when the field name is enclosed in square-brackets, it should be left untouched, but when it is not, spaces should be inserted on either side of the dash. There are no nested square brackets and the reserved word could be one or more in the string.

Comment: That is too unclear. Please explain what makes `[some-name]` special, how it can be detected. Also, do you really have to use a regex?

Comment: is that substring at the end of the string?

Comment: The string is basically user input and [some-name] is reserve word added by program. I have to add space on the sides of - if it is not in square brackets. like 3-2 will be 3 - 2 but some-name will remain unchanged as I said it is reserve word and will be detected forth.

Comment: So, in all `[...]` substrings the hyphen should stay as is, and outside of `[...]`, you need to add spaces on both sides. Right? Do you have nested brackets to consider? I mean, `[some[text-[here]]and-here]`?

Comment: Well, another question - is the `[some-name]` known (fixed) string (since it is reserved)? Is it the only reserved word? Are there more? **Please edit the question accordingly**.

Comment: There in no nested bracket and reserved word could be one or more in the string. like `Select * From [some-table] where [some-column] = 44 - [some-value]`

Comment: So, `SELECT 'some-name' FROM [some-name]` should become `SELECT 'some - name' FROM [some-name]`?

Comment: Yes exactly. But I am already using regex to add spaces like `Regex.Replace("\-", " - ", Regex.IgnoreCase)`. Now I am thinking to add condition on it to stop this if hyphen `-` is in square brackets `[]`

Comment: I will post a solution shortly. You can match the `[...]` strings with `\[[^]]+]` regex and just re-insert them, and replace all other `-`s.

Comment: @Ammar I updated the question for you, now that you've clarified what it is that you are trying to achieve.  If I got any of it wrong, feel free to correct it.  In the future, if people are confused by your questions, it's helpful if you update the question yourself, if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match and *capture* the `[...]`  substrings and then only match hyphens that are not surrounded with hyphens to replace them:

```
Dim nStr As String = "SELECT 'some-name' FROM [some-name]"
Dim nResult = Regex.Replace(nStr, "(\[.+?])|\s*-\s*", New MatchEvaluator(Function(m As Match)
                                                   If m.Groups(1).Success Then
                                                       Return m.Groups(1).Value
                                                    Else
                                                        Return " - "
                                                     End If
                                                   End Function))
```

[image]

So, what is happening is:

- `(\[[^]]+])` - matches and stores the value of `[...]` substring inside the `Group(1)` buffer (or `\[.+?]` can be used here to match a `[`, then 1 or more any characters and then `]` - with `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag so that `.` could match a newline, too)
- `(?<!\s)-(?!\s)`  - matches any hyphen not preceded (`(?<!\s)`) or followed (`(?!\s)`) with whitespace (`\s`). Actually, we may even use `\s*-\s*` (where `\s*` stands for *zero or more whitespaces* as many as possible since `*` is a greedy quantifier matching zero or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern) here to remove any whitespace there is to make sure we just insert 1 space before and after `-`.

If Group 1 matches, then we just re-insert it  (`Return m.Groups(1).Value`), else we insert the space-enclosed hyphen `Return " - "`.

Comment: Just FYI: the regex that will work with this answer can be `(\[.+?])|\s*-\s*` (perhaps, the `RegexOptions.Singleline` will be necessary for the `.` to match newlines, too). Easy to read and maintain.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribizew by replacing the regex it worked for me. Please tell me how it could be learnt?

Comment: I updated the answer and accepted the change. I do not know your level of regex knowledge :) so that I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at.

Comment: What is Group 1. If I want to check {} too then I have to change it as `"(\[.+?])|(\{.+?})|\s*-\s*"` and use Group 0 for check purpose. Right?

Comment: `Group(0)` is the whole match. `(...)` are capturing groups, and they come in the order they appear in the pattern - `Group(1)` > `(\[.+?])`, `Group(2)` > `(\{.+?})`.

Comment: I want to use the same technique in formulas. Will you please tell me how can I add special characters in it as well like `(a-b)-2` as in this case spaces are not being added. As I want the result like `(a - b) - 2`.

Comment: You mean how to replace `[` and `]` with `(` and `)`? Escape the `(` and `)` symbols. `"(\(.+?\))|\s*-\s*"`

Comment: I just want `(a-b)-2` be replaced with `(a - b) - 2` using same expression.

Comment: Then use `Regex.Replace(s, "\s*([-+*/])\s*", " $1 ")`

Comment: Please tell me any link of quick tutorial of Regex.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "(?<!\[[^-\]]*)(\w+)-(\w+)(?![^-\]]*\])", "$1 - $2")
```

Here's an explanation of the pattern:

- `(?<!\[[^-\]]*)` - This is a negative look-behind.  It asserts that matches cannot be immediately preceded by text that matches the sub-pattern `\[[^-\]]*`.  In other words, the matches we are looking for cannot be preceded by a `[` character followed by any number of characters that are not a `-` or a `]`.
- `(\w+)-(\w+)` - Matches one or more word-characters, then a dash, and then one or more word characters following the dash.  By enclosing the sub-patterns on either side of the dash in capturing groups, we can then refer to their values as `$1` and `$2` in the replacement pattern.
- `(?![^-\]]*\])` - This is a negative look-ahead.  Similar to the negative look-behind, it asserts that matches cannot be immediately followed by text which matches the sub pattern `[^-\]]*\]`.  In other words, a match cannot be followed by any number of characters that are not a `-` or a `]` and then a closing `]`.

See a [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5c%5b%5b%5e-%5c%5d%5d*)(%5cw%2b)-(%5cw%2b)(%3f!%5b%5e-%5c%5d%5d*%5c%5d)&i=SELECT+some-name%2c+some-name+FROM+%5bsome-name%5d+WHERE+%5bsome-name%5d+%3d+%27some-name%27&r=%241+-+%242).

At first glance, you might assume that you could simply assert that is must not be immediately preceded by a `[` character and that it must not be immediately followed by a `]` character.  In other words, `(?<!\[)(\w+)-(\w+)(?!\])`.  However, that pattern would still match the text `ome-nam` in the input `[some-name]` because the text `ome-nam` is not immediately preceded or followed by the brackets.

Comment: That is highly ineffcient regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew agreed.  If this is something which needs to operate on very large inputs or needs to be run many times quickly, this is not the best solution, however, it does keep the solution reduced down to a single replace using a standard pattern and replacement string.  If that's important, because the patterns are being stored in a configuration setting or something, then this may be a solution worth looking at.   If that were a requirement, can you think of a more efficient way of doing it, Wiktor?  I tried to think of a better way but couldn't.

Comment: I posted an efficient solution tailored to the current task. Using a Match Evaluator provides much better flexibility and readability to the regex and solution in general.

Comment: Right. I saw that. I was just wondering if you could think of an efficient way of doing it without a custom match evaluator.

Comment: Is there any tutorial for it as in my assigned project I will have to use it a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ammar I added more info.  Let me know if you are still confused about any of it.  It is, admittedly a bit of a confusing pattern.

Comment: I'd really like to assure you that using infinite width lookbehinds will slow down performance, and will most probably make your code harder to maintain. Use simpler regexps and let the code do the hard work.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\[[^-]*-[^-]*\]")
Dim match As Match = regex.Match("A long string containing square brackets [some-name]")
If match.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
End If
```

Or you could use `Regex.IsMatch`:

```
Return Regex.IsMatch("A long string containing square brackets [some-name]",
                     "\[[^-]*-[^-]*\]")
```

Comment: `IsMatch` is better here than `Match`. Besides, `[^-]` matches both `[` and `]`.

Comment: (I guess this also is what @WiktorStribiżew pointed out) That'll match for example `A string with square brackets [some name without a hyphen] [-]`.

Comment: @ClasG The OP did not mention that the string has to be non empty.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/jV1tI4/2). It'll match the bracketed part without a hyphen as well.

Comment: It seems now that this answer is not at all helpful - the [spaces should be added around the hyphen if they are missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247169/how-can-i-check-it-with-regular-expression?noredirect=1#comment65830809_39247169).

Answer (score 1):

Just to check if it exists, you could try

```
\[[^\]]+-[^\]]+\]
```

It matches a literal `[` and then any characters, except `]`, up to (including) a hyphen. Then again any characters, except `]`, up to a literal `]`.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dV2yU5/3).

Comment: OP says now that the [spaces should be added around the hyphen if they are missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247169/how-can-i-check-it-with-regular-expression?noredirect=1#comment65830809_39247169).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, saw that comment. It wasn't mentioned at all in the question though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Also, if you're working on this Wiktor - "I have to add space on the sides of - if it is **not in square brackets**."

Comment: That is right: I think the best approach is to match and capture what we need to keep, and match only what we need to replace. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39248609/3832970) where I am using a match evaluator to perform appropriate actions when the capture group matches or not.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't know the vb.net syntax but you can use regex as

```
/[\s\'](\w+)\-(\w+)/g
```

find the (\w+)-(\w+) which is followed by `space` or `'`  and replace your string with capture group 1st - 2nd

[See the sample here](https://regex101.com/r/xA7uN8/2)